# The new ask page is now live on the SE network!

Tags: discussion

[The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344513/the-new-ask-page-is-now-live-on-the-network)
links to Meta StackExchange and discusses an 'ask' page which is configurable for each site in the SE universe.

Specific bits that can be modified and the procedure of getting it live are here:

> **What's per-site customizable, and what's the procedure to get it live?**
>
> As you can see, any existing custom guidance on "How to ask," "How to
>   tag," or any custom error or warning messages your site may already
>   have in place will still be there, and will still be customizable with
>   the same restraints (basic HTML, using paragraphs, lists, links) as
>   before:
>
> - **The "welcome modal" for new askers**, everything between the title and "Before you
>     post..." (this is only custom on 4 sites at the moment).
> - The full contents of **the "Draft your question" sidebar**.
> - **The text in the tag popover**, between "Tags help the right people..." and the bullet points.
> - **The placeholder text in the title field** (text only)
> - **The warning text shown in the "Review your question" sidebar**, regex-based.
> - **Tag-related error messages**, regex-based.
>
> These can only be edited by staff, so the process to get them live is:
>
> - Create a Meta post on the appropriate Meta site, and discuss it with your community.
> - Once a consensus is reached, a mod should escalate it to the CM team. Generally speaking, the "contact us" form is the best way to go,
>     though a ping in chat can sometimes work too (the most that could
>     happen is we ask you to use the form).
> - Unless there are any outstanding issues, the CMs should be able to get to it Soon™.

I did not find any discussion here of the 'ask' page, so may we start a discussion?